# numpy replace array elements with numpy arrays, according to condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
subst1 = numpy.array([2, 2, 2, 2])
subst2 = numpy.array([3, 3, 3, 3])

a = numpy.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0,]])
b = numpy.where(0==a, subst1, subst2)
```

**Result:**

```
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> b
array([[3, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

**What I want:**

```
array([[[3,3,3,3], [2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,2]],
       [[2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,2]],
       [[2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,2]]])
```

I know this does not work because the `subst*` arrays are used elementwise.

It may not be possible with where, alternative solutions are also welcome.

I *want* to use numpy arrays as replacements, I know something similar can be done, if I replace the `subst*` arrays with `bytes`. I want an efficient solution, I am doing this for performance comparison with another solution - which has its own issues.

I guess this would make a 3D array out of a 2D, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = np.array([subst1, subst2])[a]

# or
out = np.vstack([subst1, subst2])[a]
```

Output:

```
array([[[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]])
```

Answer (score 4):

broadcasting:

```
b = np.where(0==a[...,None], subst1, subst2)
```

Output:

```
array([[[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]])
```

Comment: I like this solution, as well, however, I chose @mozway 's solution, because it is almost twice as fast, and it can be easily extended to have more `substN` patterns.